# Has anybody used Blpapi/Pdblp etc packages to export Supply chain data (SPLC) from Bloomberg?

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I am using pdblp package to gather supply chain data. But I am facing two problems. First, it just gives me the just first five suppliers of current date, not even all. Also, it does not give any historical data. By changing any date, still get the same results. I searched all web, there is no manual of tutorial for gathering supply chain data from Bloomberg. So, I was wondering if anybody has any experience or solution for this. Thank you so much!

The following shows my codes which I used con.bulkref_hist() and con.bulkref() in order to gather the suppliers of APPLE Inc. As shown in output, I just get 5 suppliers of Apple? Not all and even I cannot change the date.

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=True, port=8194, timeout=100000)
con.start()
con.bulkref('AAPL US Equity', 'SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS',ovrds=[('DZ414',"20100626")])


# Your code here, this should be a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Sending Request:
ReferenceDataRequest = {
    securities[] = {
        "AAPL US Equity"
    }
    fields[] = {
        "SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS"
    }
    overrides[] = {
        overrides = {
            fieldId = "DZ414"
            value = "20100626"
        }
    }
}

pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Event Type: 'RESPONSE'
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Message Received:
ReferenceDataResponse = {
    securityData[] = {
        securityData = {
            security = "AAPL US Equity"
            eidData[] = {
            }
            fieldExceptions[] = {
            }
            sequenceNumber = 0
            fieldData = {
                SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS[] = {
                    SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2317 TT Equity"
                    }
                    SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS = {
                        Equity Ticker = "4938 TT Equity"
                    }
                    SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2382 TT Equity"
                    }
                    SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS = {
                        Equity Ticker = "601138 CH Equity"
                    }
                    SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2330 TT Equity"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}





dates = ["20100626"]
con.bulkref_hist("AAPL US Equity", ["DZ405"],dates)

pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Sending Request:
ReferenceDataRequest = {
    securities[] = {
        "AAPL US Equity"
    }
    fields[] = {
        "DZ405"
    }
    overrides[] = {
        overrides = {
            fieldId = "REFERENCE_DATE"
            value = "20100626"
        }
    }
}
```

or the following:

```
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Event Type: 'RESPONSE'
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Message Received:
ReferenceDataResponse = {
    securityData[] = {
        securityData = {
            security = "AAPL US Equity"
            eidData[] = {
            }
            fieldExceptions[] = {
            }
            sequenceNumber = 0
            fieldData = {
                DZ405[] = {
                    DZ405 = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2317 TT Equity"
                    }
                    DZ405 = {
                        Equity Ticker = "4938 TT Equity"
                    }
                    DZ405 = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2382 TT Equity"
                    }
                    DZ405 = {
                        Equity Ticker = "601138 CH Equity"
                    }
                    DZ405 = {
                        Equity Ticker = "2330 TT Equity"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My outputs in both methods are the following. Not all suppliers.

```
date | ticker | field | name | value | position
-- | -- | -- | -- | -- | --
20100626 | AAPL US Equity | DZ405 | Equity Ticker | 2317 TT Equity | 0
20100626 | AAPL US Equity | DZ405 | Equity Ticker | 4938 TT Equity | 1
20100626 | AAPL US Equity | DZ405 | Equity Ticker | 2382 TT Equity | 2
20100626 | AAPL US Equity | DZ405 | Equity Ticker | 601138 CH Equity | 3
20100626 | AAPL US Equity | DZ405 | Equity Ticker | 2330 TT Equity | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: blp.bds('AAPL US Equity', 'SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS', Supply_Chain_Count_Override=10)
Out[2]:
                   equity_ticker
AAPL US Equity    2317 TT Equity
AAPL US Equity    4938 TT Equity
AAPL US Equity    2382 TT Equity
AAPL US Equity  601138 CH Equity
AAPL US Equity    2330 TT Equity
AAPL US Equity  034220 KS Equity
AAPL US Equity  005930 KS Equity
AAPL US Equity    INTC US Equity
AAPL US Equity     JBL US Equity
AAPL US Equity    2324 TT Equity
```

Btw, `DZ414` is not in the list of available overrides for `SUPPLY_CHAIN_SUPPLIERS`, and the value can only be `C` or `R`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very new to this and could not find any manual or tutorial regarding SPLC ! SO I have some other questions for you and thank you in advance: a) Can you get all suppliers or there is limit on that, I heard Bloomberg just gives the top-20? b) Can you gather historical suppliers (like the suppliers of 2017)? Since our school does not have BBA license, the positive answer to above-mentioned question can convince my advisor to upgrade our license. Thanks!

Comment: dont think historical data is available

Comment: Thank you so mcuh!